# Unable to change color of grid on click - tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, game-development

I currently have a 9x9 grid of randomly arranged green and yellow squares displayed using tkinter in python3.

[image]

**What I want to achieve -**

Let's say the user clicks on the square at position (1,4) -> where the red dot is (starting indexing from 0 where the x coordinate is the column and the y coordinate is the row).

I want the square at (1,4) to change its colour to green and every other square above it until the first occurrence of some other green square -> in this case at (1,1)

**The Problem -**

The colours are stored inside a nested list. I figured out how to change the colour of the cell that was clicked on. I also cracked the algorithm to change the elements of the list from yellow to green and vice versa however, I am not able to render those colours on the screen. So taking the same example as before, I am able to change all yellow's to green's up till (1,1), however, the grid's colour does not change.

**My code -**

```py
def on_click(pos, item):  # event handler function
    print(pos) # position -> say its (1,4)
    y_pos = pos[0] # 1
    x_pos = pos[1] # 4
    color = 'green' if color_grid[y_pos][x_pos] == 'yellow' else 'yellow'
    color_grid[y_pos][x_pos] = 'green' if color_grid[y_pos][x_pos] == 'yellow' else 'green'

    canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=color)  # *successfully* changing the colour that was clicked on

    # top
    for i in range((x_pos-1), -1, -1):
      if color in color_grid[y_pos][:(x_pos-1)]:
        if color_grid[y_pos][i] != color:
          color = 'green' if color_grid[y_pos][i] == 'yellow' else 'yellow'
          color_grid[y_pos][i] = 'green' if color_grid[y_pos][i] == 'yellow' else 'green'

          canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=color) # attempting to change the colour of the cell above the cell(s) that were clicked here

          print(f'color: {color_grid[y_pos][i]} @ {y_pos, i}') # program checkpoint

        else:
          print(f'stopped at {y_pos, i}') # another checkpoint
          break
```

Comment: You are calling `.itemconfig()` on exactly the same `item` in each iteration of your loop.  You need to save all of the items added to your Canvas (in another nested list like `color_grid`, perhaps) so that you can reconfigure them later.

Comment: Also the description in the question is checking in the y (vertical) direction, but the code is checking in the x (horizontal) direction.